# Create embedded document on object creation in Mongoid during authentication with Devise an Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid, omniauth

I have a class User

```
  class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :profile
```

and a class Profile

```
class Profile
include Mongoid::Document
include Mongoid::Timestamps

embedded_in :user
```

I'm using devise and mongoid to authenticate the user and the following method to store the user information:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      # Store information in user's profile
      user.profile.first_name = auth['info']['first-name']
      user.profile.last_name = auth['info']['last-name']
      user.profile.profile_picture = auth['info']['picture-url']
      user.profile.linkedin = auth['info']['public-profile-url']
    end
  end
```

But I'm always facing the following error

> undefined method `first_name=' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Profile object, with user as an attribute

```
profile = Profile.create({
  :user => user,
  :first_name => auth['info']['first-name'],
  :last_name => auth['info']['last-name'], ....})
```

Comment: `profile = Profile.new(:email => auth.info.email, :first_name => auth.info.first_name, :last_name => auth.info.last_name,...)
user.profile = profile` is also working and seems more natural to me